При сравнении двух вещественных чисел получаем разный результат
Сравнить два вещественных числа между собой возможно лишь с некоторой степенью точности. Если два числа отличаются на малое значение, то можно считать их равными. Необходимую степень точности мы можем задать сами.
Нужно сравнить два числа и проверить равны ли они с точностью до одной миллионной (0.000001).
Код будет выглядеть следующим образом:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      double a = console.nextDouble();
      double b = console.nextDouble();
      System.out.print(Math.abs(a-b) < 0.000001 ? "equal" : "not equal");
  }
}

если a = 12.000001, b = 12.000002 то на выходе получим not equal. Логично, ведь у нас строгий знак неравенства.
однако при значениях a = 12.000000, b = 12.000001 компилятор выдает equal, т.е считает что они равны.
Почему так происходит?

Потому что эти дроби не представимы точно. И на самом деле там не 12.000001, а (условно) 12.000000987 и 12.000002033 (значения взяты с потока, но смысл примерно такой)

@AlexeyTen, 12 представлено точно. А вот второе число искажается, тут вы правы.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как в Java сравнить 2 вещественных числа на равенство?

@NowhereMan не вижу там ответа на вопрос «Почему так происходит»

Указанные числа 12 и 12.000001 равны с точностью до миллионной, так как разность этих чисел и так составит требуемую погрешность, а фактически в двоичном представлении она будет немного меньше 9.999999992515995E-7, то есть если точность ваших чисел одна миллионная, то погрешность при сравнении должна быть хотя бы половина деления 5e-7, а лучше 10% т.е. 1e-7.

@NowhereMan, интересный дополнительный вопрос: как напечатать вещественное число с полной точностью в Java. Я не нашёл стандартного способа. Писать самому поразразрядную печать?

@StanislavVolodarskiy что-нибудь типа String.format("%.20f", a)

@AlexeyTen, этот способ я проверил. Всё равно выдаёт округлённое значение. А не должен.

@StanislavVolodarskiy я в JS проверил 12.000001.toFixed(60).replace(/0+$/,'') → 12.0000009999999992515995472786016762256622314453125

@AlexeyTen, спасибо. Я знаю что в Java, JavaScript, C++, Python это число хранится не точно. Вопрос был именно про "изобразительные" возможности Java. Я не нашёл способа распечатать точное десятичное значение именно в Java. Я ошибся? Или надо для Java делать печать руками?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, а не, я про Java ничего не знаю

@AlexeyTen, задал вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1583790

Ноги растут всё из того же IEEE 754
Числа a = 12.000001 и b = 12.000002 не представимы точно и на самом деле
a = 12.0000009999999992515995472786016762256622314453125
b = 12.0000020000000002795559339574538171291351318359375

Как видите, a немножко меньше исходного числа, а b немножко больше, и этой неточности достаточно что выполнялись неравенства
a - 12 = 0.0000009999999992515995472786016762256622314453125 < 0.000001
b - a  = 0.000001000000001027956386678852140903472900390625  > 0.000001


Спасибо! Так и думал, что дело в представлении вещественных чисел в памяти компьютера

Да и значение литерала 0.000001 ≈ 0.000000999999999999999955.

Как в том анекдоте про академика Струве в Пулково, за "вычислитель должен быть девиц". Построим неформальную модель.
Что такое a и b? Это результат форматного преобразования входных чисел, т.е. a = a₁ ± Δ₁, b = b₂ ± Δ₂, где Δ₁ и Δ₂ не превосходят Math.ulp(a)/2 и  Math.ulp(b)/2, соответственно.
Как работает Math.abs(a-b)? Результатом является |a-b| ± Δ₃.
Что такое литерал 0.000001? Он равняется 0.000001 ± Δ₄.
Таким образом, Math.abs(a-b) < 0.000001 сработает если |a₁-b₂| ± (Δ₁ + Δ₂) < 0.000001 ± (Δ₃ + Δ₄)
В случае, когда Δ₁, Δ₂, Δ₃, Δ₄, влияют на результат, т.е. в случае a ≈ b и |a-b| ≈ 0.000001, Δ₁ + Δ₂ ≲ Math.ulp((a + b)/2) ≈ Math.ulp(a), а Δ₃ + Δ₄ ≲ Math.ulp(0.000001).
Теперь что такое сравнить и напечатать? Здесь у нас два варианта, либо печатать три сообщения: "равны", "различны" и "кто его знает", либо гарантировать один случай - "equal", а область неопределённости отнести к его отрицанию - "not equal".
И тогда выражение, которое гарантирует, что "equal" выдаётся только тогда, когда гарантировано |a₁-b₂| < 0.000001, может выглядеть так:
Math.abs(a-b) + Math.ulp(a) < Math.nextAfter(0.000001, Double. NEGATIVE_INFINITY)

nextAfter не нужен, если машинное представление 0.000001 меньше десятичной дроби 0.000001.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, нет, не совсем, т.к. Δ₃ - ошибка операции вычитания всё равно остаётся. К тому же завтра может быть не 0.000001, а литерал 0.00001, который больше числа 0.00001. Так что, какой ни какой, а автомат нужен.
